# Openvz VE issues after upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, openvz

i'm running openvz on ubtunu Lucid (kernel 2.6.32.28-openvz-pae).
the templates i used are ubuntu 10.04 ones.

i tried to upgarde one of my two VEs from 10.04 to 10.10.

The process was broken (the upgrade didn't finished. I googled and found some solutions ( https://forum.ramhost.us/bbs/viewtopic.php?id=330 ) to finish the upgrade but my VE still hungs after few hours of a restart because of lake of memory.

any shell commands returns: "-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory"

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance

Comment: also when i had these error messages, i can't connect using ssh to the container.

Comment: You should put that comment above in an answer and accept it :)

Comment: Sorry, i missed toupdate my post. 

I found un answer on [link]`(forum.ramhost.us/bbs/viewtopic.php?id=330)

So it suggests to make some update in your sysctl.conf file: 
`
# sed -i 's/kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1/#kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1/g' /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf 
# sed -i 's/net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1/#net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1/g' /etc/sysctl.d/10-network-security.conf 

# sed -i 's/vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536/#vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536/g'   /etc/sysctl.d/10-zeropage.conf # sed -i 's/kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7/#kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7/g' /etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i missed toupdate my post.

I found un answer on [RamHost Forum](http://forum.ramhost.us/bbs/viewtopic.php?id=330)

So it suggests to make some update in your sysctl.conf file:

```
# sed -i 's/kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1/#kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1/g' /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf 
# sed -i 's/net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1/#net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1/g' /etc/sysctl.d/10-network-security.conf 
# sed -i 's/vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536/#vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536/g'   /etc/sysctl.d/10-zeropage.conf 
# sed -i 's/kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7/#kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7/g' /etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf
```